# Trying to create an R function which finds the input value in column 1 of a dataframe and returns column 2 value of the same row

Tags: r

New to R functions, I have a dataframe which looks like this except about 10,000 rows long:

| Gene.name | Ortho.name |
| --- | --- |
| abc | DEF |
| qrs | TUV |
| wx | YZ |

I'm trying to create a really simple function in r which when I input qrs, returns TUV. If someone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: what does it output when the imput is not qrs?

Comment: This is unclear, but looks as a case for `ifelse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
fun <- function(vec, data) data$Ortho.name[ match(vec, data$Gene.name) ]
Z <- structure(list(Gene.name = c("abc", "qrs", "wx"), Ortho.name = c("DEF", "TUV", "YZ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

fun("qrs", data = Z)
# [1] "TUV"
fun("nothing", data = Z)
# [1] NA
fun(c("qrs", "abc", "not found"), data = Z)
# [1] "TUV" "DEF" NA
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is using seurat for plotting orthologs in a cross-species comparison, this is how I implemented the above using orthologs from BioMart:

```
chick_fish_ortho <- read.csv("chick_orthos.csv")
mac_fish_ortho <- read.csv('mac_orthos.csv')

macfun('glula', mac_fish_ortho)
chickfun('glula', chick_fish_ortho)

chickfun <- function(vec, data) data$Chicken.gene.name[ match(vec, data$Gene.name) ]
macfun <- function(vec, data) data$Macaque.gene.name[ match(vec, data$Gene.name) ]

fish_chick_mac <- function(gene, chickdata, macdata) {
  p1 = FeaturePlot(object = fish_MG, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE,  min.cutoff = 0, features = gene) 
  p2 = FeaturePlot(object = chick_MG, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE,  min.cutoff = 0, features = chickfun(gene, chickdata))
  p3 = FeaturePlot(object = mac_MG, reduction = "umap", label = TRUE,  min.cutoff = 0, features = macfun(gene, macdata))
  p1 + p2 + p3
}

fish_chick_mac('glula', chick_fish_ortho, mac_fish_ortho)
```